# Determining specs for a power supply for a mystery motor

Tags: motor, test

I have a set of 4 motors for an automatic backdrop system for a photographer studio.

How can I determine what I need to run these? They would normally come with a box with switches that operate them (rolling one way to lower the backdrops, the opposite way to raise them), but those switches are lost.

There's no label on any of the motors.

ELI5: how can I run tests to determine what power supply I need? I assume a Momentary DPDT switch will work?

I have a lovely Multimeter from Harbor Freight. Top of the line operation over here.

Comment: Which multimeter is it?

Comment: Do you know if they are battery or line operated? Do you have a make and model of the system? How many wires come out of the motor? How heavy are the backdrops? With enough information like this we might take a guess.

Comment: Some pictures of the motors would help a lot, and their mechanical arrangement and any wiring.